# Get Data from parse.com Promises

Tags: parse-platform, promise

I am trying to use parse.com promises to retrieve job data as well as user relation data associated with the job. I have a function that returns promises but not job data. How do I get the job & employee information from the returned promises?

Logically I want to:
1) Query Parse to get array of jobs
2) For each job, query Parse again to get the employee relation information
3) Create local object that contains job & employee details 
4) Add each job object to local array
5) Load table with array of objects once all information has been retrieved from Parse

I can do steps 1-4 but I can't figure out how to wait until all information has been retrieved from Parse to refresh the local table.

```
function getJobPromises (){

      var promises = [];

      var Job = Parse.Object.extend("Job");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Job);
      query.equalTo("company", company);
      query.notEqualTo("isDeleted", true);
      query.limit(1000); // raise limit to max amount
      query.find().then(function(results) {
        // Create a trivial resolved promise as a base case.
        var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

        _.each(results, function(result) {
          // For each item, extend the promise with a function to add it to the job array
            promise = promise.then(function() {
              // Return a promise that will be resolved when the job details have been added to the array


                var object = result;

                promises.push(getEmployeeName(object));


                allJobDataArray = promises;


            });

        });

        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

      }).then(function() {
        // Every job has been retrieved
        console.log("All items have been returned. Refresh table...");
        console.log(allJobDataArray);


      });
}
```

The function that does the relational query to get the users associated with the job

```
function getEmployeeName(jobObject) {

    var employeeNameArray = [];

      //Query to get array of employees for the passed in job
      var rQuery = jobObject.relation("employee");
      return rQuery.query().find({
        success: function(employees){

            //Get employees full name for each job
            for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
              var objEmployee = employees[i];
              var fullName = objEmployee.get("fullName");
              employeeNameArray.push(fullName);
              console.log(employeeNameArray);


            }
        },
        error: function(error){
          response.error(error);
        }

      });  

   }
```

**Update**
It is now working thanks to @eduardo

I have a public array to hold the job objects.

var jobObjectsArray = [];

In the getEmployeeName function I am creating the job objects and adding them to that array

```
function getJobPromises (){
        var promises = [];
        var Job = Parse.Object.extend("Job");
        var query = new Parse.Query(Job);
        query.equalTo("company", company);
        query.notEqualTo("isDeleted", true);
        query.limit(1000); // raise limit to max amount
        query.find().then(function(results) {
          _.each(results, function(result) {
            promises.push(getEmployeeName(result));
          });

          return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

        }).then(function(allJobDataArray) {
          // allJobDataArray should be actually an Array of Array
          console.log(jobObjectsArray);
          refreshTable();

        });
      }

      function getEmployeeName(jobObject) {
        var employeeNameArray = [];

        //Query to get array of employees for the passed in job
        var rQuery = jobObject.relation("employee");

        return new Promise(
          function(resolve, reject) {
            rQuery.query().find({
              success: function(employees){
                //Get employees full name for each job
                for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                  var objEmployee = employees[i];
                  var fullName = objEmployee.get("fullName");
                  employeeNameArray.push(fullName);

                  var objAllJobs = new Object();

                  objAllJobs["jobId"] = jobObject.id;
                  objAllJobs["location"] = jobObject.get("location");
                  objAllJobs["startTime"] = jobObject.get("startTime");
                  objAllJobs["employee"] = employeeNameArray;

                  jobObjectsArray.push(objAllJobs);

                }
                console.log(employeeNameArray);
                resolve(employeeNameArray);
              },
              error: function(error){
                reject(error);
              }
            });
          }
        );
```

Comment: You are calling `Parse.Promise.when(promises);` when the promises have *not* yet been added to the array.

Comment: You're somehow mixing sequential iteration with parallel mapping. Which do you want?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to not have the last then function called until I have both the job information and employee information for each job. I am trying to create an object with the job details and load it into a table. Previously I was not using promises and the table refresh was happening before I could get all of the data back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a few incorrect uses of the promise concept. I will go through  them, but first here is the final code:

```
function getJobPromises (){
  var promises = [];
  var Job = Parse.Object.extend("Job");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Job);

  query.equalTo("company", company);
  query.notEqualTo("isDeleted", true);
  query.limit(1000); // raise limit to max amount
  query.find().then(function(results) {

    _.each(results, function(result) {
      promises.push(getEmployeeName(result));
    });

    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

  }).then(function(allJobDataArray) {
    // allJobDataArray should be actually an Array of Array
    console.dir(allJobDataArray);
    console.log(allJobDataArray[0]);
  });
}

function getEmployeeName(jobObject) {
  var employeeNameArray = [];

  //Query to get array of employees for the passed in job
  var rQuery = jobObject.relation("employee");

  return rQuery.query().find({
    success: function(employees){

      //Get employees full name for each job
      for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        var objEmployee = employees[i];
        var fullName = objEmployee.get("fullName");
        employeeNameArray.push(fullName);
      }
      console.log(employeeNameArray);
      return employeeNameArray;
    },
    error: function(error){
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
}
```

"Parse.Promise.as()" should be used only if you have a value that you want to return as a promise. Something like:

```
Parse.Promise.as("my value").then(function(foo) {
  console.log(foo) // "my value"
});
```

So if your "getEmployeeName" function is returning a promise, which means that this "rQuery.query().find" returns a promise, you don't have to create a new promise or use the "Parse.Promise.as()", it is already a promise and you can push it to the promises array.

Another problem was that you were not return anything in the "getEmployeeName" method callback. Take a look into my version, I'm returning "employeeNameArray".

My version will only work if this "rQuery.query().find" method returns a promise. If that is not the case, you can create a new promise using its callbacks like this:

```
function getEmployeeName(jobObject) {
  var employeeNameArray = [];

  //Query to get array of employees for the passed in job
  var rQuery = jobObject.relation("employee");

  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      rQuery.query().find({
        success: function(employees){
          //Get employees full name for each job
          for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            var objEmployee = employees[i];
            var fullName = objEmployee.get("fullName");
            employeeNameArray.push(fullName);
          }
          console.log(employeeNameArray);
          resolve(employeeNameArray);
        },
        error: function(error){
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Please notice this "new Promise()" depends on the browser support of Promise, I don't know if Parse has an equivalent. Anyways you can use it with a polyfill that implements the necessary code if the browser has no support.

More about standard promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Polyfill: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I ran the code and in the console for console.dir(allJobDataArray); and  console.log(allJobDataArray[0]); its only returning one array with two user items. I can see it printing the arrays from console.log(employeeNameArray); before this but in the final then its like its only returning the employees for one job. not all 12 that the Job query is returning `Array[2]
ParseUser {_objCount: 44, className: "_User", id: "uHWPYwuedW"}`

How can I get the returned value to be an array of job objects with a property that is an array of employee names for that job?

Comment: If I run your second function for getEmployeeName its still only returning one array with two employees but this time its their actual names `Array[2]
0: "Actual Employee Name 1"1: "Actual Employee Name 2"length: 2__proto__: Array[0]
wt'`

Comment: So "getEmployeeName" is being called many times and printing all the jobs?

Comment: I got it working. Thanks again for all your help. I posted the updated code in my original question.